# Looking for some Wordpress Plugin that is able to manage different users and create automatically a page for each of them

Tags: wordpress

It should be able to create a page, for example: www.mypage.com/new_user
There the new users posts should get displayed in chronological order. It would also be very nice if they could create their own posts and edit them directly from the website being logged in and not within the WP-Admin Panel.

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this, You can use plugin like **Ultimate Member**. 
It is used to create front end user registration, user profiles, login, custom form builder, member directory. The plugin makes it a breeze for users to sign-up and become members of your website.
The plugin allows you to add beautiful user profiles to your site and is perfect for creating advanced online communities and membership sites.
This plugin is also able to show author posts & comments on user profiles

To Read more features go to [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/)

Also see other similar plugins at https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/membership/